# What would be an alternative to x:Reference?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have XAML that looks as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CdTeThickness">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row = "0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox x:Name="DisplayMarkers"   Content="Display Data Points" Margin="8,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="False"/>
                <CheckBox x:Name="DisplayIndicator" Content="Display Indicator"   Margin="8,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="False"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <vf:Chart Grid.Row = "1" Style="{StaticResource chartStyle}" IndicatorEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference DisplayIndicator}, Path=IsChecked}">
                <vf:Chart.Titles>
                    <vf:Title Text="{Binding Chart.ChartTitle}"/>
                </vf:Chart.Titles>
```

My understanding is that x:Reference is not widely supported yet. However, this is the only way I was able to bind to the desired property (DisplayIndicator), as shown in the screen shot. Can someone suggest an alternative to x:Reference that will work in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often you can use an [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) binding, however [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx) *is* actually well supported.

```
{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=DisplayIndicator}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, as an alternative to direct binding, you could bind both the `Checkbox.IsChecked` and the `Chart.IndicatorEnabled` enabled to a property (e.g. ChartDisplayMarkers) on your viewmodel.